# What are some good options for museums/memorials to learn more about the history of Jim Crow/lynching

Tags: usa, museums, illinois, wisconsin

I will be visiting Illinois and Wisconsin later this year (hopefully including a [concert with Rage against the machine](https://tour.ratm.com/)).

While staying there I would like to visit a museum or memorial place to learn more about the history of Jim Crow, lynching and suppression of black people.

Any recommendation would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can visit **America's Black Holocaust Museum** at 401 W North Avenue, Milwaukee, Wisconsin.

Please see the [ABHM](https://www.abhmuseum.org/visit/) website.

> ABHM builds public awareness of the harmful legacies of slavery and Jim Crow in America and promotes racial repair, reconciliation, and healing.

Comment: That seems like a very good option.

Comment: We did visit this museum. It was smaller than I had expected. Thanks to having listened to several episodes of the podcast [Teaching hard history](https://www.learningforjustice.org/podcasts/teaching-hard-history) a good portion of the information was already known to me (which I guess is a testament to the quality of the podcast), but I still appreciated the visit. I bought a copy of James Cameron's memoir.

Answer (score 6):

While it does not focus solely on the Jim Crow period, the [**DuSable Museum of African American History**](https://www.dusablemuseum.org/exhibitions/) (740 East 56th Place, Chicago, Illinois) does have some exhibits that connect with the period, including:

- *Un(re)solved*, about racist murder cases (including lynchings) that were re-examined under the [Emmett Till Unsolved Civil Rights Crime Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmett_Till_Unsolved_Civil_Rights_Crime_Act)
- *Freedom: Origin and Journey*, a journey through several periods of the African-American experience
- *Troubled Waters: Chicago 1919 Race Riot*, about the [race riot of 1919](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_race_riot_of_1919) and the historical circumstances surrounding it

It is not clear from the website whether these exhibitions are permanent or temporary, so you may wish to check the website closer to your visit to see what will be on display.